# Create custom Listener on FirebaseInstanceIdService to implements in activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any possibility to create interface and listener in `FirebaseInstanceIdService` class and implements it in activity?

Because I was trying to do that and I got error.

Here is my code :

```
public class _FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    private static Context mContext = null;

    private  onListener mListener = null;




    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        mListener=(onListener)this; //i got error in here
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.e(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        if (!refreshedToken.isEmpty()){
            boolean b = PreferencesManager.init(this).saveToken(refreshedToken);

            if (b)
                if(mListener != null)
                    mListener.onTokenListener(refreshedToken);
        }

    }
    // [END refresh_token]




    public interface onListener{

        void onTokenListener(String token);
    }

}
```

the error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: rezkyaulia.android.dont_do.services._FirebaseInstanceIDService cannot be cast to rezkyaulia.android.dont_do.services._FirebaseInstanceIDService$onListener
    at rezkyaulia.android.dont_do.services._FirebaseInstanceIDService.onTokenRefresh(_FirebaseInstanceIDService.java:55)
```

I'm wondering if it can be do or not. Really need advice.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the issue because your service is not implemented with onListener as you are initialising it using 'this' it means you are refering the implementation to the same class but I got what you are looking for:

> You want dynamic binding between service and some other class which
>   implement the listner, but I'm going to suggest a lengthy way to do it
>   because
>
> FirebaseInstanceIdService

is a service and use of interface from service is not suggested, you can take update from service by sending Broadcast if your app is not running and if your app is running then use IPC to do it and send token from messenger

In Your activity or fragment use the code below
Step 1: Create Incoming Handler

```
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MessengerService.MSG_SET_VALUE:
                        mCallbackText.setText("Received from service: " + msg.obj);
                        break;
                    default:
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Target we publish for clients to send messages to IncomingHandler.
         */
        final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
```

2: Create Service Connection:

```
 /**
     * Class for interacting with the main interface of the service.
     */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // established, giving us the service object we can use to
            // interact with the service.  We are communicating with our
            // service through an IDL interface, so get a client-side
            // representation of that from the raw service object.
            mService = new Messenger(service);
            mCallbackText.setText("Attached.");

            // We want to monitor the service for as long as we are
            // connected to it.
            try {
                Message msg = Message.obtain(null,
                        MessengerService.MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT);
                msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
                mService.send(msg);

                // Give it some value as an example.
                msg = Message.obtain(null,
                        MessengerService.MSG_SET_VALUE, this.hashCode(), 0);
                mService.send(msg);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // In this case the service has crashed before we could even
                // do anything with it; we can count on soon being
                // disconnected (and then reconnected if it can be restarted)
                // so there is no need to do anything here.
            }

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
            mService = null;
        }
    };
```

3: Call Binding before calling get Token

```
    void doBindService() {
            // Establish a connection with the service.  We use an explicit
            // class name because there is no reason to be able to let other
            // applications replace our component.
            bindService(new Intent(MessengerServiceActivities.this,
                    MessengerService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            mIsBound = true;
        }
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

4: Finally in your FirebaseInstanceIdService class

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Keeps track of all current registered clients.
     */
    ArrayList<Messenger> mClients = new ArrayList<Messenger>();
    /**
     * Holds last value set by a client.
     */

    /**
     * Command to the service to register a client, receiving callbacks
     * from the service.  The Message's replyTo field must be a Messenger of
     * the client where callbacks should be sent.
     */
    public static final int MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT = 1;

    /**
     * Command to the service to unregister a client, ot stop receiving callbacks
     * from the service.  The Message's replyTo field must be a Messenger of
     * the client as previously given with MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT.
     */
    public static final int MSG_UNREGISTER_CLIENT = 2;

    /**
     * Command to service to set a new value.  This can be sent to the
     * service to supply a new value, and will be sent by the service to
     * any registered clients with the new value.
     */
    public static final int TOKEN_REFRESHED = 3;

    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT:
                    mClients.add(msg.replyTo);
                    break;
                case MSG_UNREGISTER_CLIENT:
                    mClients.remove(msg.replyTo);
                    break;
                case TOKEN_REFRESHED:
                    for (int i = mClients.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        try {
                            mClients.get(i).send(Message.obtain(null,
                                    TOKEN_REFRESHED, msg.arg1, 0));
                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                            // The client is dead.  Remove it from the list;
                            // we are going through the list from back to front
                            // so this is safe to do inside the loop.
                            mClients.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null,
                TOKEN_REFRESHED);
        msg.obj = refreshedToken;
        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     * <p/>
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
        Log.e("", "FCM Token: " + token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... i will try it :)

Answer (score -1):

The `FirebaseInstanceIdService .onTokenRefresh` is implemented by a service. It cannot be implemented in an activity.

Token refresh cannot be monitored an activity, because a token refresh can also happen when your app is not active. Since activities won't be running when the app is killed, you'll have to implement `FirebaseInstanceIdService .onTokenRefresh` in a service to handle the token refresh.